# Getting the unused argument error while running climpact Rscript?

Tags: r

I was trying to run the sample file of climpact for the historical and I got the error

error in create.indices.from.files(infiles, outdir, file.template, author.data, :
unused arguments (root.dir = root.dir, ehfdef = EHF_DEF, wsdin_n = 5, csdin_n = 5, hddheatn_n = 18, cddcoldn_n = 18, gddgrown_n = 10, rxnday_n = 7, rnnmm_n = 30, ntxntn_n = 3, ntxbntnb_n = 3, project.lat2d.coords = TRUE)
Execution halted

Could you please help me on how to solve this? Thanks in advance.

```
library(climdex.pcic.ncdf)

infiles=c("climpact.sampledata.gridded.1991-2010.nc")



vars=c(prec="precip",tmax="tmax", tmin="tmin")


outdir="TestIndex"


file.template="var_daily_climpact.sample_historical_NA_1991-2010.nc"


author.data=list(institution="My University", institution_id="MU")


base.range=c(1991,2010)


cores=FALSE


indices=NULL    #c("hw","tnn")


thresholds.files=NULL#"./www/output/gridded/thresholds.test.1991-1997.nc"


root.dir=NULL



# Esoterics below, do not modify without a good reason.


EHF_DEF = "PA13"

axis.name="Y"


maxvals=10


fclimdex.compatible=FALSE

create.indices.from.files(infiles,outdir,file.template,author.data,variable.name.map=vars,base.range=base.range,parallel=cores,axis.to.split.on=axis.name,climdex.vars.subset=indices,thresholds.files=thresholds.files,fclimdex.compatible=fclimdex.compatible,root.dir=root.dir,
                         cluster.type="SOCK",ehfdef=EHF_DEF,max.vals.millions=maxvals,wsdin_n=5,csdin_n=5,hddheatn_n=18,cddcoldn_n=18,gddgrown_n=10,rxnday_n=7,rnnmm_n=30,ntxntn_n=3,ntxbntnb_n=3,project.lat2d.coords=TRUE,
                          thresholds.name.map=c(tx05thresh="tx05thresh",tx10thresh="tx10thresh", tx50thresh="tx50thresh", tx90thresh="tx90thresh",tx95thresh="tx95thresh", 
                                                tn05thresh="tn05thresh",tn10thresh="tn10thresh",tn50thresh="tn50thresh",tn90thresh="tn90thresh",tn95thresh="tn95thresh",
                                                 tx90thresh_15days="tx90thresh_15days",tn90thresh_15days="tn90thresh_15days",tavg90thresh_15days="tavg90thresh_15days",
                                                tavg05thresh="tavg05thresh",tavg95thresh="tavg95thresh",
                                                txraw="txraw",tnraw="tnraw",precraw="precraw", 
                                                 r95thresh="r95thresh", r99thresh="r99thresh"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to run after removing the line "root.dir=NULL"

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the keyword arguments mentioned in the error. By this way can figure out the problem. After that you maybe encounter an error with code 4090 from `R_nc4_create`, you must explicitly create the output path defined the var of `outdir`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).